# Add Users of Sql Table in FBA

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Hi all,

My client is using PHP site and now he is migrating to SharePoint 2010.

In the PHP site my client have up to 10000 members and my client uses MySQL as back-end for the PHP site. I have converted the MySQL table to SQL Server table. This table consists of users' passwords and user names and some other fields.

Now I want to add these people into SharePoint FBA. So that the existing users of PHP site can login with same user name and password to my new SharePoint site directly with out any registration.

Can any one help me how can I do add it?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options

1. Implement custom RoleProvider and Membership provider that will access your custom SQL database with user credentials. Then you will need to configure SharePoint to use those providers for authentication.
2. Create new ASP.NET SQL provider SQL database ([instructions here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx)). And implement simple migration script that will read credentials from your MySQL DB and import them into this ASP.NET SQL database. Then you won't need to implement Role/Membership providers as you can use the existing one that comes with SharePoint.

Both are relatively straightforward, so I would suggest you evaluate functionality that the ASP.NET SQL provider offers (how lost password is restored using it, what fields can you store for the user, etc.) and determine if it would work for you. If it suits your needs, consider using it. If it has some shortcomings, I believe it is better to implement your own providers.

Also in the end you will probably want to modify the migration script and turn it into scheduled (or triggered) task that will synchronize new users and other changed data from MySQL to SQL Server.